# how to use OpenCV 2.3.1 to connect to IP Camera?

Tags: c++

I'm using openCV 2.3.1 to connect to IP Camera.

Here is my code

```
#include "../../../OpenCV/include/opencv/cv.h"
#include "../../../OpenCV/include/opencv/highgui.h"

CvCapture *camera = cvCreateFileCapture("http://usr:pass@ip:port/nphMotionJpeg?resolution=320x240&Quality=Standard");
    if (camera == NULL)
        printf("camera is null\n");
    else
        printf("camera is not null");

    cvNamedWindow("img");
    int d = cvWaitKey(10);
    while (d != atoi("q"))
    {
        d = cvWaitKey(10);
        double t1 = (double)cvGetTickCount();
        IplImage *img = cvQueryFrame(camera);
        double t2=(double)cvGetTickCount();
        printf("time: %gms  fps: %.2g\n",(t2-t1)/(cvGetTickFrequency()*1000.), 1000./((t2-t1)/(cvGetTickFrequency()*1000.)));
        cvShowImage("img",img);
    }
    cvReleaseCapture(&camera);
```

But above cvCreateFileCapture() function always return null, but if i use cvCreateFileCapture("video.avi") is ok, please explain to me why?

I have read many threads about this issue on stackoverflow.com, but i dont have any way to solve this problem yet.

I'm using OpenCV 2.3.1, and I have built it with ffmpeg (i'm not sure this, but i had opencv_ffmpeg.dll on my folder after build it).

Comment: It looks like `cvCreateFileCapture` supports only local files.

Answer (score 2):

As [the documentation says](http://opencv.jp/opencv-1.0.0_org/docs/ref/opencvref_highgui.htm), you can only pass the path to a local file to cvCreateFileCapture().

If you want to use openCV on an IP camera, you'll have to fetch images from the server by another mean, and then analyze the frames individually with openCV.

Comment: Really? I dont see document mention a local file. I have read many threads and there are some people was successful with this code.
But if it true, can you show me the other way to connect to IP Camera?
Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using LibIpCurl. It support connection to Ip camera.